# Was Severus Snape ever loved/liked romantically by a woman?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

Is there any evidence that Severus Snape from J.K. Rowling's Harry Potter was ever loved romantically by a woman? If so, please provide evidence that he was loved - canon evidence only, please.

Comment: You could argue that Lily may have at least liked him romantically for a time.

Comment: Well, if you count his out-of-universe fangirls then sure! :P

Comment: Honestly, probably not.  Lily did care for him for a while, but he was in love with her and only her for his entire life.  I can't imagine if there are any women he'd be around who would care for him.

Answer (score 12):

JKR says "no". In an [1999 radio interview for WBUR Boston](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-connectiontransc2.htm#p13), she explicitly confirmed that Snape is utterly unlovable (by others) and implicitly confirmed that *his* only love was for Lily (who's dead).

> **Lydon:** *Er - one of our connec- ... one of our internet correspondents wondered if Snape is going to fall in love?*
>
> **JKR:** *Yeah? Who on earth would want Snape in love with them, that is a very horrible idea. Erm ...*
>
> **Lydon:** *But you'd get an important kind of redemptive pattern to Snape*
>
> **JKR:** *It is, isn't it ... I got ... There's so much I wish I could say to you, and I can't because it'd ruin ... I promise you ...
> whoever asked that question, can I just say to you that I'm - I'm
> slightly stunned that you've said that - erm - and you'll find out why
> I'm so stunned if you read book 7. And that's all I'm going to say.*

If JKR says that no woman would want to *be* loved by Snape, it follows logically that the opposite must be true (e.g. that no woman could love him, because who would want their love to be unrequited?).

Comment: Where does she say no? "Who on earth would want Snape in love with them" is technically a question, not a statement, right? (Even though the easiest way to interpret it is as a rhetorical question implying "there is no such person.")

Comment: @sumelic - I really don't see any other way to interpret it. If you listen to her tone in the audio (rather than reading the transcript) her meaning is crystal clear.

Comment: That's the Snape of "today", and note that this is before the release of Snape's memory (DH). I don't have a reference, but didn't JKR specifically mentioned that if it weren't for Snape's increasing obsession with Dark Arts, Lilly would have...?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin - I don't disagree with what you're saying. By the same token, however,  nothing in DH suggests that he enjoyed her romantic love

Comment: @Valorum It is also possible JKR was trying to trick the readers or keep them in the dark, since the interview is from 1999, and only 2 or 3 books has come out at that time. Any little hint of his affiance with Lily could have ruined the twist we see at the end.

Comment: @Valorum in no way does this answer the question. at all.

Comment: @ava - If no woman would want Snape to be in love with her, it's reasonable to assume that that works the other way. What kind of woman would love him **but not want to be loved by him in return?** It's logically contradictory unless the woman was in some way mentally defective.

Comment: that doesn't address lily specifically, who seems to be the exception rather than the rule, so to speak. @Valorum

Comment: There's zero indication that she thinks of him in any way romantically.

Comment: there's zeri indication that she didn't think of him romantically. read into it what you will. @Valorum